# MouseEvent not dispatching on movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3

I know this must be easy but somehow I have not been able to figure it out after spending more than hours. I have two movie clips in a class that extends Sprite. When I add event listener to the stage every thing works fine. But when I try to add event listener to one of the movie clips, the event never dispatches it seems. Here is how it looks like -

```
public class MyClass extends Sprite
{
    private var movieclip1:MovieClip, movieclip2:MovieClip;

    private function init(e:Event == null):void
    {
         movieclip1 = new MovieClip();
         movieclip2 = new MovieClip();
         //works fine, dispatches event
         stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN. mousedown);
         //not working
         movieclip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);
         addChild(movieclip1);
         addChild(movieclip2);
    }
}
```

Actually I want both the movie clips to work mutually exclusively, i.e., a mouse event on one movie clip should not interfere with that of the other. Any pointers?

Comment: try stage.movieclip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN); if not then try this instead of stage

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting errors? You should be getting errors. How do you even know it doesn't dispatch the event? You have no callback functions.

Comment: I'd expect this code to throw a syntax error at this line `e:Event == null` and `Error 1136` at both event listeners.

Comment: The movieclip are empty?

Comment: Is that all the code of the class?  You have no constructor, and nothing is calling your private init() function.

Comment: @MartonPallagi Ofcourse I have a call back function. Did not mention here. I am using Alert.show() inside callback method. I don't see an alert pop up in later case.

Comment: @SharpEdge Yes. I need to use one of them for free hand drawing on MOUSE_MOVE event.

Comment: @Gigggas Ya of course. I just posted the snippet as I thought this is the contentious part. There is constructor that calls init() and that's it.

Comment: @MortanPallagi Sorry about that. Forgot to mention the name of the function in the event listener.Edited the code snippet in the question.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the movieclip in question? MouseEvents don't trigger on transparent areas.

Comment: @Mortan Pallagi Actually can't. Office project. But there is nothing transparent here.

Comment: @raghav If MovieClip is empty its size is 0,0 and it's obvious that you don't get events.

Comment: @subrat71 stage.movieclip1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown) throws compile time error. It says "Error:Access of possibly undefined property movieclip1 through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage".

Comment: @SharpEdge Ya but this class extends from Sprite.And I have instantiated this class in my main mxml file and added the object to spark component SpriteVisualElement(<s:SpriteVisualElement>).And this flex component has height and width. Do I still need to explicitly specify the dimensions of movie clips?

Comment: you need to put this code in a mxml component and make a object over your required view where create the object then it will work.

Comment: instead of movieclip try swfloader and call the init() and see there is no swf object.

Answer (score 2):

Empty MovieClips and Sprites CANNOT be sized, they will be 0,0 and then they will not be able to dispatch MouseEvents.

You can resize a MovieClip when it has some content.
The Sprite will be of the size of the rectangle that encloses the 2 MovieClip.

If the MovieClips are empty = 0,0 the Sprite will be 0,0

About the events between the 2 MovieClips:
They are not going to interfere because the events when are bubbling goes upwards.

So the listeners put on MC1 will listen ONLY onClick on MC1 and the same does MC2

Comment: Thanks for the response.But the later part of my question has no answers yet. How do I handle both the movie clips in a way that event on one do not bother the other or one movie clip does not come to know of events happening to the other one.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean. What you are asking has no sense. When you click on MovieClip1 it will dispatch an event and caught by the listener put on the MovieClip1, same thing when you click on 2

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the width and height of the movieclip1 or movieclip2, you will get 0 both.
So, you can't click them.

You can use graphcis to draw a shape in these two mcs, and try again.

Comment: Ya but this class extends from Sprite.And I have instantiated this class in my main mxml file and added the object to spark component SpriteVisualElement(<s:SpriteVisualElement>).And this flex component has height and width. Do I still need to explicitly specify the dimensions of movie clips?